# MySQL / Sorting and grouping data by date

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to group the data to me that they just want the last record of each ID, what should I do?

In access to solve my problem this way:

```
SELECT Table1.id, Last(Table1.status) AS LastStatus, Last(Table1.date) AS LastDate
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Tabele1.id;
```

My table

```
 ____________________________
|  ID  | STATUS |    DATE    |
|123456|   1    | 15/04/2016 |
|123456|   2    | 16/04/2016 |
|123456|   3    | 17/04/2016 |
|123456|   1    | 18/04/2016 |
|654321|   3    | 19/04/2016 |
|654321|   4    | 20/04/2016 |
|654321|   2    | 21/04/2016 |
|98765 |   3    | 22/04/2016 |
|98765 |   1    | 23/04/2016 |
|98765 |   2    | 24/04/2016 |
|98765 |   3    | 25/04/2016 |
------------------------------
```

The desired result is the last record of each ID.

```
 ____________________________
|  ID  | STATUS |    DATE    |
|123456|   1    | 18/04/2016 |
|654321|   2    | 21/04/2016 |
|98765 |   3    | 25/04/2016 |
------------------------------
```

Comment: `select max(date)... group by id, status`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a where in with a subquery that return thx max date for the id

```
select * from my_table 
where (id, date)  in (  select id, max(date)  
                        from my_table 
                        group by id   )
order by date
```

or if you need order by status

```
select * from my_table 
where (id, date)  in (  select id, max(date)  
                        from my_table 
                        group by id   )
order by status
```

Comment: It works, but has otherwise no subquery? (Thank you for your help).

Comment: I know this way  .. why you don't like subquery .. you need a subset for matching the max(date) and this is the simplest way ..

Comment: I like subqueries, the problem is that I will use enough subqueries.

Comment: Another way is more complex and with a more heavy impact on performance .. in this case i think is the most convenient solution ..

Comment: Well anyway .. if my answer ir right  .. is fair mark it as accepted ..

Comment: I do not have enough points to do so. I'm sorry!

Comment: Mark as accepted is always possible. also with 1 point only.. you have 9 and when you accept an asnwer you obtain +2 points. Is mark as useful that require 15..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm new here. I have done the mark, thank you!